# Is this field conservative?

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm looking for a potential of this field:

$ F=\frac{f(r)}{r} (x,y,z) $  where $ r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} $ and $ f $ is a $ C^1 $ function.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried? Off the top of my head I can think of writing it as the gradient of a scalar potential or trying to verify path independence of line integrals of $F$. What was the result of those investigations?

Comment: Here's a hint: What does the chain rule have to say about the gradient of $F(r)$ with $r$ as you've defined and $F$ equal to the antiderivative of $f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g$ be an anti-derivative of $f$, i.e., $g'=f$, then it can be easily show that
$$
\nabla g(r)=f(r) \frac{(x,y,z)}{r},
$$
since
$$
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{r},\,\,\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}=\frac{y}{r}
\,\,\,\text{and} \,\,\,\frac{\partial r}{\partial z}=\frac{z}{r}.
$$
This shows that the field is conservative, as
$$
\int_a^b F\big(\gamma(s)\big)\cdot \gamma'(s)\,ds=g\big(\gamma(b)\big)-g\big(\gamma(a)\big),
$$
i.e., the integral is independent of the route we followed - it only depends on the endpoints.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!!